Prove that the complement of the language L = { <T> : T is a Turing machine that runs in polynomial time } is not turing recognizable
To show that L is not Turing-recognizable, we can use a reduction from the complement of the ATM problem (ATM'). However, I'm not sure about how we would prove that the complement of L is not Turing-recognizable. I'm wondering if we could just use the same from as for L but instead of rejecting if ATM' accepts and vice versa, but I don't understand these well enough to understand if that's feasible.

Hint: Are you familiar with the halting problem?
